# Convert address of pointer to string and assign a string adress to pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a problem with address of a pointer.

class:

```
class name{
public:
    name();

}
```

I want to get address of a pointer of the name class and convert it to string

```
name* p=new name();
const char* add=(const char*)&p;
printf("%s \n",add); // input is ������� . how to transfer add to string to use printf("%s \n",add) and result is 0xbfa0f108 ??
printf("%p \n",add); //input is 0xbfa0f108 


name *q;
q= add; // i want to assign the address of q to point to p. indirect via add.
```

How do i need to do? I am a new in c++;

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Why do you need to convert the `name*` pointer indirectly to a `char*` in the first place? You can't print it using `%s`, only with `%p`.  And you can't assign it to `q` without an ugly type-cast, eg: `q = *((name**)add);`. What are you really trying to accomplish? This sounds like an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking.  Do you want to print the pointer?

Comment: The real problem: i want to get address of an object in C and pass address to Lua, then i'll put back the address to C. I need to convert the address pointer to string to pass easy to Lua.

Answer (score 4):

To get the string of the address of a pointer to the name class, you just write:

```
name* p = new name(); // pointer to name class
const char* add = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&p);
std::string str = add;
```

You can retrieve an address to an object in a couple ways:

```
type* pntr = &object;
```

In the above example, pntr is now an address to object. The & symbol, when used on the right hand side of a statement, specifies that you want an address. When used on the left hand side of a statement, & specifies a reference to another object:

```
type& ref = object;
```

In this example, ref is now a reference to object. Setting ref equal to another value will set object equal to that value.

When you have a pointer, and you want the object that that pointer points to, just use the * symbol to dereference the pointer:

```
type* pntr = &object; // pntr is the address pointing to object
std::cout << *pntr << std::endl; // dereferences pntr to retrieve object
```

Like @vishal said, q = add will throw an error because you are assigning a **const char*** to a **name***. You can't directly assign one type of pointer to another type like this. Also, casting away const is not considered bad practice, but you must be absolutely certain that you know what you are doing. It is, however, considered bad practice to use C-style casts in c++. If you want to cast, you should use one of the following:

```
static_cast<type*>(pointerToSomeOtherType);
reinterpret_cast<type*>(pointerToSomeOtherType);
const_cast<type*>(pointerToSomeOtherType);
dynamic_cast<type*>(pointerToSomeOtherType);
```

not

```
(type*) pointerToSomeOtherType;
```

Comment: no the line q = (name*) &add; does not throw any error,  q will get address of add, you can verify by cout<<q;

Comment: @vishal My bad! I missed the &. On another note, q = (char*) add compiles for me, when I use actual types. I thought that the compiler would throw an error if you try to cast away constness without using a const_cast... why doesn't it in this case?

Comment: @ Alexander Bolinsky:The really problem: I am working with Lua script and i created an object in c+++, i want to pass the address of the object to Lua and put back the address from Lua to C++. should i do that? I don't know how to pass a object to Lua and pass back that object from Lua to C++.

Comment: @ vishal: I was trying and i saw that it cannot get address of add

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the address of the pointer just use &.

change:

```
printf("%s \n",add);
```

to:

```
printf("%p \n",&add);
```

or better use cout //as this question is tagged to c++

```
cout<<&add;
```

> i want to assign the address of q to point to p. indirect via add.

well you cannot do:

```
 q = add; // name * and const char ** are different pointer types.
```

You can assign q as reference to add by casting it to name *

```
q= (name *) &add;  // not a good practice 
cout<<q<<endl;
```

this is not a good practice for casting const char * because:

*const char* is a pointer, who's value can be also changed, that points to   a location containing a value of type char that **cannot** be changed.*